# Should I use a partition or is there a better way?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table structure, simplified like so:

```
period_id int
suite_id varchar(20)
suite_status varchar(50)
```

Each month is assigned to a period id. Each suite has a record for each month (period_id). Suite status's can be either 'Vacant' or 'Active Lease'. I'm trying to write a query that shows the top five deals that have been leased since the 1st of July 2011 that were vacant the longest before they became an active lease but I don't know how to approach this.

My original approach was to rank each lease by the number of periods that it was vacant, like so:

```
;WITH cte_vacancy_periods AS
(
        SELECT  lp.suite_id ,
                count(lp.period_id) AS 'Periods Vacant'
        FROM    property.lease_period lp
        WHERE   lp.suite_status = 'Vacant'
                        OR
                        (       isnull(lp.suite_status, '') = ''
                                AND     lp.lease_id = 'No Lease'        )
        GROUP BY
                lp.suite_id
        ORDER BY count(lp.period_id) desc
)
```

I was then planning to cross-reference this with the leases made active since period 258 (the 01-July-2011).

Unfortunately this doesn't work in cases where a lease was vacant for two months, then leased for a month then vacant for two more months (showing a total of four months vacant before being leased when it should really be two).

I'm sure this could be done with a partition but I've come up short trying to do this and don't quite understand them. What am I missing in my knowledge for approaching this problem? If I've explained the data poorly so it's hard to understand what I'm trying to do please let me know and I'll elaborate where I can.

Comment: What if a suite was vacant before 1st July 2011, and then became leased after that date?  When counting the number of consecutively vacant periods, should those periods preceding July 2011 be included in the count?

Comment: @Dems Oh dear. I explained that very poorly! Basically - I want to show leases that were lease since 1st July 2011 to present ranked by how many months they were vacant for before being leased. When they became an active lease doesn't matter provided it's after 01-July-2011 (period 258)

Comment: and yes, the number of months vacant before 01-July should be counted. Just want to know how many months in a row the lease was vacant for prior to being leased

Comment: @Michael, Can you please provide some sample data and the result you want to get from these data with a brief explanation of the criteria you want to select these results?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Putting together a sql fiddle now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully an approach something like this will help.

I have to admit that I'm not 100% clear on what final result you're looking for, but this should get you a data-set that can answer many quesions similar to yours.

```
WITH
  reformatted_data
AS
(
  SELECT
    suite_id,
    period_id,
    CASE
      WHEN suite_status = 'Vacant'                                 THEN 0
      WHEN lease_id = 'No Lease' AND isnull(suite_status, '') = '' THEN 0
                                                                   ELSE 1
    END as suite_status
  FROM
    properties.lease_period
)
,
  gaps_and_islands
AS
(
  SELECT
    suite_id,
    period_id,
    suit_status,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY suite_id               ORDER BY period_id) AS seq,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY suite_id, suite_status ORDER BY period_id) AS seq_status
  FROM
    reformatted_data
)

SELECT
  suite_id,
  suit_status,
  MIN(period_id)       AS first_period_id,
  MAX(period_id)       AS last_period_id,
  MAX(seq) - MIN(seq)  AS consecutive_periods
FROM
  gaps_and_islands
GROUP BY
  suite_id,
  suite_status,
  seq - seq_status
```